# Can you aggregate Azure API gateways?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I hope this isn't a stupid question.

Imagine an enterprise which somehow has ended up with more than one production instance of an Azure API gateway.

There might be various reasons for this, maybe this happened because different projects pay for each gateway, maybe the owners of each gateway want to configure different features (e.g. differences in support for TLS versions etc).  Maybe Project X wants to iterate fast without the possibility of bringing down other APIs served through the gateway.

Can you unite multiple gateway instances through a single endpoint without doubling the cost?  - a kind of gateway of gateways?

Comment: I dont think I understand the question properly, because I dont really understand it :) but you cannot merge api gateways.

Comment: I have re-read my initial query and edited it to be more of a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about pulling configuration from several instances of APIM service and putting it into one instance, it is possible, but there is no automation or it. Easiest way would be to export each instance configuration into separate Git repository. Manually move aggregate it in another Git repository and then import it into single instance as a whole. Your mileage may vary depending if there are any conflicting settings in those instances.

Comment: i dont think everything gets exported into git? like, certificates, dont?

Comment: You're right. Git export has no secrets. If you need those then manual synchronization via API is your best bet.